# Problem with $AM>GM>HM$ inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Question:** Let $a=1.2.3.4.5$ Then, prove that

> A) $5^5>a$
>
> B) $5^5>6a$
>
> C) $3^5>5!$

**My Approach:**
By the $AM>GM>HM$ inequality we have,$$\frac{1+2+3+4+5}5>a^\frac{1}{5}$$
From here we get that $$3^5>a$$, which implies
$$3^5.5!$$
My question is, how do I use this approach to obtain proofs for the remaining parts?

Comment: Do we really need AGH for (A)?

Comment: Without $AGH$, proving $(A)$,$(B)$ is no hassle at all. I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it using the inequality.

Comment: If you really want to use AM-GM to prove $n^n>(n+1)!$ (which for $n=5$ gives B, which is stronger than A), note that the obvious factorizations use $n$ ($n+1$) factors on the left (right), so you'll need to add non-obvious factors. Note also it has to be a proof strategy that only works for $n\ge3$.

Comment: These numbers are so small that you can get away with just computing the expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$5>1,~~5>2,~~5>3,~~5>4,~~5=5$$
Multiplying these we prove that $$5^5 > 5!$$

Next note that $$4 >3,~~5>4,~~5>3,~~5>4,~~5=5$$
Multipluing them, we get
$$5^5 > 6~~ 5!$$